# "Module (User) could not be initialized" : Exception in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have downloaded the skeleton application of Zend Framework 2. Then I am creating a module named "User".

Folder structure;

```
Module
  .....
  User
   config
      module.config.php
   src
      Controller
        UserController.php
      Model
        User.php
        UserTable.php
      Form
      Module.php
   view
      index.phtml
      ...
```

I have added 'User' in application's modules.config.php

```
return [
  'Zend\Form',
  'Zend\Db',
  'Zend\Router',
  'Zend\Validator',
  'Application',
  'User',
];
```

My Module.php code is as follow;

```
<?php
 namespace User;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [

            Model\UserTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\UserTableGateway::class);
                return new Model\UserTable($tableGateway);
            },

            Model\UserTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\User());
                return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ],
    ];
}

public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\UserController::class => function($container) {
                return new Controller\UserController(
                    $container->get(Model\UserTable::class)
                );
            },
        ],
    ];
}
}
```

Inside composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "User\\": "module/User/src/",
    }
},
```

But I am getting the error "Module (User) could not be initialized". I am new to Zend Framework. I think something is wrong in Module.php. I tried all answers in **stackoverflow**. Most of them indicates **namespace** issue. But I think I have given it correct.
Can you please point out the issue please, if more code needed please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. The issue is the comma(,) at the end of "User\": "module/User/src/" , in composer.json

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `PSR-4` by your folder structure, I don't see `Module.php`, but it should be inside `src` directory.

Also, make sure you added your module to `composer.json`, the same way `Application` module is added:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "User\\": "module/User/src/",
    }
},
```

Then update composer's autoload files by:
`$ php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Comment: I did both of these. Updated my question accordingly. No result still. Just lost here. Stack tracing the exception if I find something. Please let me know if you can catch the error.

Comment: Ok, solved. The issue is the comma(,) at the end of "User\\": "module/User/src/" , in composer.json